# Single page application tracking with gtag.js Not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX-X">
</script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX-X');
</script>
```

The above gtag google analytics worked on the first time when the page is fully loaded. after site loads, new page content dynamically rather than as full page loads then gtag google analytics is not worked, we tried to update the page_path, modify the config property by specifying a value for the page_path parameter e.g `gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/new-page.html'});` but this solution not worked.

We referred to [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications) for the solution.

Comment: and you've replaced GA_TRACKING_ID with your actual property ID (eg `UA-XXXX-X`)?

Comment: yes i have replaced GA_TRACKING_ID with my property ID